# Training conversations using sequence models

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a question regarding training conversations, the context is that the next statement is not necessarily a function of the previous statement but also of any statement in the body of conversation for example:

person1: what is your favorite food and restaurant
person 2: my favorite food is burger and McDonald is my fav restaurant
Person1: why do you like burger
person 2: because i dont care about the health aspect while eating
person1: why do you like mcdonalds when there are so many places where you can buy a burger

now as we can see the last question was derived from an answer received 3 steps before...
In this context how do i train an lstm so that it remembers all the previous contexts..
essentially i am looking for an approach to create my training data and output sentence..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that LSTM will give you sufficient long-term memory for the example conversation you posted. You will likely need to use some sort of transformer memory network to maintain context. Take a look at approaches for the "persona chat" problem as well as [this recent paper](https://research.fb.com/publications/learning-to-speak-and-act-in-a-fantasy-text-adventure-game/) on handling conversational context.